# node-gyp error on npm install: fatal error C1083 on bson and kerberos compilation

Tags: c++, node.js, windows-10, node-gyp, build-tools

Does anyone around have a solution path to overcome this issue successfully?

I found this error on following a nodejs, express, mongodb tutorial on Windows.

My environment is Windows 10 x64, nvm for windows (using v.012.7 x64).
Environment has vs2015 c++ build tools installed, and python 2.7 (x64) and the system is using it.
node-gyp was installed globally via npm install.

The compilation error I got (for a number of files on bson and kerberos) is the following:

```
D:\projects\express-tut\nodetest1> npm install

> bson@0.2.22 install D:\projects\express-tut\nodetest1\node_modules\bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


D:\projects\express-tut\nodetest1\node_modules\bson>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Javier\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v0.12.7\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Los proyectos de esta solución se van a compilar de uno en uno. Para habilitar la compilación en paralelo, agregue el modificador "/m".
  bson.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory [D:\projects\express-tut\nodetest1\node_modules\bson\build\bson.vc
xproj]
```

You can see a more detailed summary of the issue in gist and the screen capture below:

https://gist.github.com/javlc/67220256c6e51573dc07

Screen capture of the error (Shown twice).
http://imgur.com/aSQV3vs

Your help resolving this is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have build tools installed correctly (both Windows 8.1 sdk and Windows 10 sdk), you can try these commands in cmd.exe, if you haven's already:

- npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global
- reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7 /v 14.0 /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^%programfiles(x86)^%"\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\"
- SET PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\Bin;%PATH%

It should work after that. You can find more information here: [1](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-158163655), [2](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245), or in other posts in that discussion.

Comment: Hi, I'd rather avoid touching the regedit. If this is needed for this line of processing, I'd leave it off.